# How do they update the points in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

When a faculty member awards points to a house, are the hourglasses immediately updated by telepathy or do they have some other procedure to complete?

Comment: ... magic? There's a scene where McGonagall is handing out loads of points and the hourglasses just update as she is speaking.